# Map enum values to a generic type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use a generic to set a flexible `value` type for a given `parameter`. `Parameter` is an enum which defines what type of value can be used e.g. `Parameter.DURATION` should only accept a number however, there's clearly something wrong as it also accepts a string and I have no idea why. Perhaps there's a better way to map those types and enum values together.

Take a closer look at what `setParameter()` accepts when you hover over the call. It shouldn't accept `string | number`, it should accept `number` only.

> function setParameter(parameter: Parameter, value: string | number): void

```
type ParameterType = string | number | boolean;

enum Parameter {
    ID = 'ID',
    TAG = 'TAG',
    DURATION = 'DURATION',
}

type ParameterNativeType = {
    [Parameter.ID]: string;
    [Parameter.TAG]: string;
    [Parameter.DURATION]: number;
}

function setParameter<T extends Parameter>(parameter: Parameter, value: ParameterNativeType[T]) {
  console.log(`Setting ${parameter} to ${value}`);
}

setParameter(Parameter.DURATION, '3');
```

Here's a link to [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwsCCAq5oF4oDOwCAlgHYDmUAPlGQK7IBGGNUTA9hwDYRxkBuAFBCIDZLEQo0rAN5CoiqAEkAIlHwByNZoA0CpZgCCAcQ1RNxk3oOLVAVQBKRzMoDyAOXOaHz155sAXxFQSEkkVHQEDzhgEgA3CGww-HklKABteAiZBAA6NQBdAC5CYnIKYXSsqUiMPKsSstJKKqUanKi83xd3DybxFgRhYKEAM3oyAGM4jjJCNGzpKIAeTCgIAA90MgATAnDljAA%20AAowWtzSpbqEXSh4uG56CGvLqJi4xOSIDMxCgCUUDSUCmcwIPAgeW4HAopwABgBlNBxShQAAksgunQwgSgwA4GNkj2eEEC8IBIxEBEW7wwpxuuW6Tl6nnumgAzJpKUA)

Perhaps defining what the `Parameter` is might help but couldn't the function figure it out from the `parameter` argument somehow?

```
setParameter<Parameter.DURATION>(Parameter.DURATION, '3');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was tricky one! You're not using `T` for `parameter` type, that's why `T` is not inferred from provided argument and `value` type is not narrowed. Should be:

```
function setParameter<T extends Parameter>(parameter: T, value: ParameterNativeType[T]) {
  console.log(`Setting ${parameter} to ${value}`);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwsCCAq5oF4oDOwCAlgHYDmUAPlGQK7IBGGNUTA9hwDYRxkBuAFBCIDZLEQo0rAN5CoUAJIARKPgDkqjQBoFUTAEEA4uqgajx3fpUBVAEqHMSgPIA5MxruPn76wF8RUEhJJFR0BDc4YBIANwhsEPx5RQBteDCZBAA6VQBdAC5CYnIKYTSM6Qjsy0Li0kpyqHSpcIxs7ydXNzrxFgRhQKEAM3oyAGMYjjJCNEq2hAAeTCgIAA90MgATAlCqjAA%20AAowVqyizB0oWLhueggi%20ayomPjEiFTMPIBKKBSocbTAg8CDZbgcChHAAGAGU0DFKFAACSyU6ZCL%20KDADjI2Q3O4QfxQ76DEQEOZnCJHJ7VTq%20NxXDQAZg0JKAA)